# ionic 2: How to show menutoggle button on child page

Tags: angular, ionic2

I want to show the 'menu toggle' button on child page of side menu app. How can I do this? Currently, the back button is present on the child pages and the menu toggle button is only on the root page.

Answer (score 4):

Check [menu toggle](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/menu/MenuToggle/)

```
 <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
```

Add it in the header of child pages.

Try

```
<ion-menu [content]="content" persistent="true">
```

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/menu/Menu/ . set persistent attribute in your menu tag

Comment: `ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    
      <button ion-button menuToggle>
        <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    <ion-title>Convoy</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>` this is the code

Comment: add your menu code and child header code in the question.

Comment: Menu code: `<ion-menu [content]="content">

  <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-title>Pages</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>

  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <button ion-item *ngFor="let p of pages" (click)="openPage(p)">
        {{p.title}}
      </button>
      <button ion-item (click) = "exitApp()">
        Exit
      </button>
      <button ion-item (click) = "refferFreind()">
        Reffer a friend
      </button>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>

</ion-menu>

<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav>`

Comment: child page: `<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    
      <button ion-button menuToggle>
        <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    <ion-title>Convoy</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>`

Comment: it showned on child page, but it doesn't populate and open list when clicked on it

Comment: even in the root page?

Comment: its working on root page, but in child it only for showing, not working(populated, opened list)

Comment: its working only on root page , not in child page. In child page it display only.

Comment: Now I noticed that , child pages after a modal page has this problem. When i travel to this child pages not via the modal ,there is no problem. menu is working

Comment: How are you exiting the modal?

Comment: thats not I am saying, when i go to the child pages via a modal page then toggle menu doesn't work(but it display). Otherwise menu toggle button work well.

Comment: you are injecting navcontroller in the modal?

Comment: no, in my app profile page(child page) shows after checking the username and password in a modal . in this way menu toggle button in profile page is not working. When i bypass the modal, the menu toggle button in the profile page is working

Comment: you are doing viewcontroller.dismiss() from the modal or go login->modal->profile?

Comment: yes, I dismiss the modal, but menu toggle button is not working

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that I was not dismissing the modal.
In your modal do it like this:

```
 forward(){
    this.view.dismiss({goHome: 'goHomeN'});    
  }
```

In your page where you create handle like this:

```
    const myModal = this.modal.create('ConfirmModalPage');
    myModal.onDidDismiss(data => {
      if(data.goHome == 'goHomeN') {
        this.navCtrl.push('TestPage');
      }
    });
    myModal.present();
```

And https://stackoverflow.com/a/41163503/6517383 helped me.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of:

```
this.navCtrl.push(YourPage)
```

Use setRoot

```
this.navCtrl.setRoot(YourPage)
```

Fixed it for me.

Comment: He asked about child page. Using setRoot() they're no more child page but root page.